# source blocks within qanda answers

Tags: asciidoctor

I want to create a Q&A with Asciidoctor.

Most of the answers involve command line instructions, which I want in `[source]` sections. However, it seems that the `[source]` block marks the end of the `[qanda]` block.

```
[qanda]
How do you show all the changes introduced in branchA since its common ancestor commit with branchB?::
    Having branchA and branchB as valid pointers, run
[source,sh]
----
$ git log branchB..branchA
----
You probably mean branchA and branchB to be recently related.

How do you see the contents of a stash?::
    `git stash show -p "stash{0}"`
```

The second question is displayed as the first element of a labeled list.

Is there a way to express that in Asciidoctor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a "+" in the line before `[source,sh]`. Complete file should then look like:

```
[qanda] 
How do you show all the changes introduced in branchA since its common ancestor commit with branchB?::
Having branchA and branchB as valid pointers, run
+
[source,sh]
----
$ git log branchB..branchA
----
You probably mean branchA and branchB to be recently related.

How do you see the contents of a stash?::
`git stash show -p "stash{0}"`
```